# How to create a dataframe, which contain 2D list under a key?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have created a dictionary, which contains following data

x = {'a': [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]],
'b':  [[7,8,9],[10,11,12]]}

I want to create a dataframe that look something like this,

[image]

How should I achieve it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create DataFrames in list comprehension and join togeher by [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
df = pd.concat({k: pd.DataFrame(v).T for k, v in x.items()}, axis=1)
print(df)
   a     b    
   0  1  0   1
0  1  4  7  10
1  2  5  8  11
2  3  6  9  12
```

Another idea is use dict comprehension for change format of original (performance should be better):

```
d = {(k, i):y for k, v in x.items() for i, y in enumerate(v)}
print (d)
{('a', 0): [1, 2, 3], ('a', 1): [4, 5, 6], ('b', 0): [7, 8, 9], ('b', 1): [10, 11, 12]}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
print (df)
   a     b    
   0  1  0   1
0  1  4  7  10
1  2  5  8  11
2  3  6  9  12
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Is it possible to change column name that is below a, b from 0,1 to something like 'index_0' and 'index_1', using method 1 that you have provided.

Comment: @Shaji Thorn Blue change `pd.DataFrame(v).T` to `pd.DataFrame(v).T. add_prefix('index')`

Comment: My main moto of asking the question is how should I change row and column name which is a member of single key now, for example currently index 'a' has two column 0 and 1. Is it possible to change it to completely different names, suppose first column we can name 'abc' and second column we can name 'xyz' which is currently 0 and 1 for key 'a'. I will really appreciate if you could let me know if this kind of changes possible with first method you have mention i.e. list comprehension. Thankyou

Comment: @Shaji Thorn Blue Then simplieat is use rename like `df = df.rename(columns={0:'abc', 1:'xyz'}, level=1)`

Comment: @jezral Thank for all the help, This is how I was doing it till now,
`df = pd.DataFrame()
    for k, v in x.items():
        df_zero = pd.concat({k: pd.DataFrame(v[0], columns=['abc'])}, axis=1)
        df_one = pd.concat({k: pd.DataFrame(v[1], columns=['xyz'])}, axis=1)
        frame = [df, df_zero, df_one]
        df = pd.concat(frame, axis=1)`
But, your answer is more concise.